# How to replace specific trailing characters but block the first two letters

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, gsub

I want to harmonize strings by replacing all trailing Xs and Ys with underscores. Since the length of those strings varies, I wrote the following regex which works fine. However, the first **two** characters should always stay as they are. I know that I could use `substr()` and `paste0()` as a workaround but how can I include this "do not replace the first two characters" in the regex?

```
x <- c("AXZ", "AZXYYX", "HZX_Y", "BXX", "XYX_")

# replaces all trailing X / Y
gsub("[XY](?=[XY_]*$)", "_", x, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "AXZ"    "AZ____" "HZ___"  "B__"    "____"

# blocks first character
gsub("(?<!^)[XY](?=[XY_]*$)", "_", x, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "AXZ"    "AZ____" "HZ___"  "B__"    "X___"

# desired output
c("AXZ", "AZ____", "HZ___", "BX_", "XY__")
#> [1] "AXZ"    "AZ____" "HZ___"  "BX_"    "XY__"
```

I already managed to exclude the first letter so I guess it should be an easy fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following approach seems to work:

```
gsub("(?<=.{2})[XY](?=[XY_]*$)", "_", x, perl=TRUE)

[1] "AXZ"    "AZ____" "HZ___"  "BX_"    "XY__"
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern, which uses lookarounds to enforce the correct replacements:

```
(?<=.{2})        lookbehind and assert there exist at least 2 preceding characters;
                 this ensures replacement will never be made on first 2 characters
[XY]             match any of X or Y
(?=[XY_]*$)      lookahead and assert that previous X/Y/_ is only followed
                 by more X/Y/_ until the end of the string
```

Note that we replace one character at a time with underscore, but we use `gsub` so that all necessary replacements will happen.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and the explanation! This looks neat and economical! I just think we do not have to replace underscores with underscores, therefore `(?<=.{2})[XY](?=[XY_]*$)` should be fine?

Comment: @mnist Yes, you are correct, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Wonderful solution!

Answer (score 3):

You may just skip the first two characters using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
x <- c("AXZ", "AZXYYX", "HZX_Y", "BXX", "XYX_")

gsub("^.{2}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[XY](?=[XY_]*$)", "_", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Which yields

```
[1] "AXZ"    "AZ____" "HZ___"  "BX_"    "XY__"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vF526k/1).

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Could you explain how the regex is working? Especially what the combination of SKIP and FAIL and | achieves.

Comment: Good answer. You may want to change your link to [this](https://regex101.com/r/vF526k/2), which is simply your link with the substitutions shown (.../2 rather than .../1).

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is to capture the preceding two characters and repeat them. You can use '\1', '\2' etc. in the substitution string to refer to the 1st, 2nd, etc. capture groups respectively. Here we have only one capture group.

```
sub("(..)[XY]+$)", "\\1_", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: @mnist The error is because the `)` after the dollar sign should be omitted.

Comment: Then result is not as desired